# ID rows containing values greater than corresponding values based on a criteria from another row

Tags: pandas

I have a grouped dataframe. I have created a flag that identifies if values in a row are less than the group maximums. This works fine. However I want to unflag rows where the value contained in a third column is greater than the value in the same (third) column within each group. I have a feeling there shoule be an elegant and pythonic way to do this but I can't figure it out.

The flag I have shown in the code compares the maximum value of tour_duration within each hh_id to the corresponding value of "comp_expr" and if found less, assigns "1" to the column flag. However, I want values in the flag column to be 0 if min(arrivaltime) for each subgroup tour_id > max(arrivaltime) for the tour_id whose tour_duration is found to be maximum within each hh_id. For example, in the given data, tour_id 16300 has the highest value of tour_duration. But tour_id 16200 has min arrivaltime 1080 which is < max(arrivaltime) for tour_id 16300 (960). So flag for all tour_id 16200 should be 0. 
Kindly assist.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
stops_data = pd.DataFrame({'hh_id': [20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20044,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,20122,],'tour_id':[16300,16300,16100,16100,16100,16100,16200,16200,16200,16000,16000,38100,38100,37900,37900,37900,38000,38000,38000,38000,38000,38000,37800,37800],'arrivaltime':[360,960,900,900,900,960,1080,1140,1140,420,840,300,960,780,720,960,1080,1080,1080,1080,1140,1140,480,900],'tour_duration':[600,600,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,420,420,660,660,240,240,240,60,60,60,60,60,60,420,420],'comp_expr':[1350,1350,268,268,268,268,406,406,406,974,974,1568,1568,606,606,606,298,298,298,298,298,298,840,840]})
stops_data['flag'] = np.where(stops_data.groupby(['hh_id']) 
               ['tour_duration'].transform(max) < stops_data['comp_expr'],0,1)
```

This is  my current output:[Current dataset and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRv14.jpg)

This is my desired output, please see flag column: [Desired output, see changed flag values in bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cufqT.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help. 
Please don't include images in your question.

Comment: Stack overflow is not allowing me to add data samples as I am a new user. That's why I had to include images of the dataset.

Comment: I added the code to create the dataframe. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    >>> stops_data.loc[stops_data.tour_id
    .isin(stops_data.loc[stops_data.loc[stops_data
    .groupby(['hh_id','tour_id'])['arrivaltime'].idxmin()]
    .groupby('hh_id')['arrivaltime'].idxmax()]['tour_id']), 'flag'] = 0

    >>> stops_data
        hh_id  tour_id  arrivaltime  tour_duration  comp_expr  flag
    0   20044    16300          360            600       1350     0
    1   20044    16300          960            600       1350     0
    2   20044    16100          900             60        268     1
    3   20044    16100          900             60        268     1
    4   20044    16100          900             60        268     1
    5   20044    16100          960             60        268     1
    6   20044    16200         1080             60        406     0
    7   20044    16200         1140             60        406     0
    8   20044    16200         1140             60        406     0
    9   20044    16000          420            420        974     0
    10  20044    16000          840            420        974     0
    11  20122    38100          300            660       1568     0
    12  20122    38100          960            660       1568     0
    13  20122    37900          780            240        606     1
    14  20122    37900          720            240        606     1
    15  20122    37900          960            240        606     1
    16  20122    38000         1080             60        298     0
    17  20122    38000         1080             60        298     0
    18  20122    38000         1080             60        298     0
    19  20122    38000         1080             60        298     0
    20  20122    38000         1140             60        298     0
    21  20122    38000         1140             60        298     0
    22  20122    37800          480            420        840     0
    23  20122    37800          900            420        840     0
```

Comment: This is perfect and EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you!